# Looping through a list (with sublists) and assign the matching IDs to the same key and all of the corresponding values from that sublist?

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary, unique-key

I'm quite new in python coding and I can´t solve the following problem:

I have a list with trackingpoints for different animals(ID,date,time,lat,lon) given in strings:

```
aList = [[id,date,time,lat,lon],
         [id2,date,time,lat,lon],
         [...]]
```

The txt file is very big and the IDs(a unique animal) is occuring multiple times:

i.e:

```
aList = [['25','20-05-13','15:16:17','34.89932','24.09421'],
         ['24','20-05-13','15:16:18','35.89932','23.09421], 
         ['25','20-05-13','15:18:15','34.89932','24.13421'],
         [...]]
```

What I'm trying to do is order the ID's in dictionaries so each unique ID will be the key and all the dates, times, latitudes and longitudes will be the values. Then I would like to write each individual ID to a new txt file so all the values for a specific ID are in one txt file. The output should look like this:

```
{'25':['20-05-13','15:16:17','34.89932','24.09421'],
      ['20-05-13','15:18:15','34.89932','24.13421'],
      [...],
 '24':['20-05-13','15:16:18','35.89932','23.09421'],
      [...]
}
```

I have tried the following (and a lot of other solutions which didn't work):

```
items = {}
for line in aList:
    key,value = lines[0],lines[1:]
    items[key] = value
```

Which results in a key with the last value in the list forthat particular key :

```
{'25':['20-05-13','15:18:15','34.89932','24.13421'],
 '24':['20-05-13','15:16:18','35.89932','23.09421']}
```

**How can I loop through my list and assign the same IDs to the same key and all the corresponding values?**
Is there any simple solution to this? Other "easier to implement" solutions are welcome!

I hope it makes sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding all the lists that match to the same ID as list of lists:

```
aList = [['25','20-05-13','15:16:17','34.89932','24.09421'],
         ['24','20-05-13','15:16:18','35.89932','23.09421'],
         ['25','20-05-13','15:18:15','34.89932','24.13421'],
         ]

items = {}
for line in aList:
    key,value = line[0],line[1:]
    if key in items:
        items[key].append(value)
    else:
        items[key] = [value]

print items
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{'24': [['20-05-13', '15:16:18', '35.89932', '23.09421']], '25': [['20-05-13', '15:16:17', '34.89932', '24.09421'], ['20-05-13', '15:18:15', '34.89932', '24.13421']]}
```